# How to interpret repeated measurements

Tags: anova, repeated-measures, interpretation, pspp

I am working on a clinical therapeutic study as a PhD student and I have a question about repeated measurements.

The study focuses on wake therapy, I have about 60 patients and 15 healthy controls. The main changes are examined via questionnaires, and the most data is compared between "before" vs "after therapy". However, additionally, every patient and control filled out a scale from 1 to 10 every two hours over the main course of the sleep deprivation on mood and tiredness.

So, I calculated the means and plotted the data, and there are indeed some interesting movements. Now, I was told to "examine this further" - unfortunately, I have no idea how to do that.

I ran an ANOVA to know if the differences between my groups is significant or not in every measured point in time. But I really don't know how to further analyze such data. Are there any recommended approaches on how to analyze repeated measurements? It's the only repeatedly measured variable in my whole study, so I am standing in front of something completely new here. ;) What tests could make sense here?

I am working with PSPP 0.10.2.